# Where on Stack Exchange should one ask questions about SAP configuration and process?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a "how might one approach this problem in SAP" question, but I'm not looking for a programming answer, since I want process and configuration suggestions, not customisation.

Despite there being an SAP tag on Stack Overflow, it is not technically a programming issue, so in theory it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow.

However, as SAP configuration is so complex and variable, it could conceivably be regarded as a very high level language, and thus become eligible for Stack Overflow?

What does the community think? Am I going to get downvoted, etc. for asking this kind of question on the SAP tag on Stack Overflow?

Comment: It feels broad if not opinion based. I don't expect it to fly on SO. Not sure if there is any other SE site that will take it.

Comment: Superuser has a [SAP tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sap) though it's not very active.

Comment: *Might* go on [sf] too, if it's just configuration (*managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks* is on-topic) which also has a [`sap`](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sap) tag. However, "process" is not something you'll find much support for.